# Match first row of first column if matched then send its corresponding row of second column into Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am having an excel with two columns Requirement and Source. I have another Word document with Requirement which are there in excel. I want it to be matched. If it is matched then its corresponding source need to be sent to Requirement in word document.
[The excel file data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0Q3.png)

In the word document the data should be displayed like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Fjl.png)

I tried in this way:

```
Sub SearchItem()
  Dim shtSearchItem As Worksheet
  Dim shtExtract As Worksheet
  Dim oWord As Word.Application
  Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
  Dim oDoc As Word.Document
  Dim oRange As Word.Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim CurrRowShtSearchItem As Long
  Dim CurrRowShtExtract As Long
  Dim myPara As Long


  On Error Resume Next

  Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

  If Err Then
    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    WordNotOpen = True
  End If

  On Error GoTo Err_Handler

  oWord.Visible = True
  oWord.Activate
  Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("File Location")     

  Set shtSearchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=shtSearchItem
  End If
  Set shtExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

  LastRow = shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows(shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

  For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 2 To LastRow
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
      With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While oRange.Find.Execute = True
            oRange.Select
            If .Found Then
                oRange.InsertAfter ("Reference" & ":")   ' <= what need to be done?


            End If
            oRange.Start = oRange.End
            oRange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       Wend
     End With
  Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

  If WordNotOpen Then
    oWord.Quit
  End If

  'Release object references

  Set oWord = Nothing
  Set oDoc = Nothing

  Exit Sub
  Err_Handler:
  MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
  If WordNotOpen Then
    oWord.Quit

  End If

End Sub
```

Please Help. Thank You

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: I am unable to fetch the corresponding source of a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub SendRefsToDoc()
'Note: A reference to the Word library must be set, via Tools|References
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, StrNm As String
Dim r As Long, xlFList As String, xlRList As String
StrNm = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\MyDocument.docx"
If Dir(StrNm) <> "" Then
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      If .Range("A" & r).Text = "" Then
      xlRList = xlRList & ", " & Trim(.Range("B" & r))
      Else
        xlFList = xlFList & "|" & Trim(.Range("A" & r))
        xlRList = xlRList & "|" & Trim(.Range("B" & r))
      End If
    Next
  End With
  With wdApp
    .Visible = False
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=StrNm, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      For r = 1 To UBound(Split(xlFList, "|"))
        With .Range
          With .Find
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = Split(xlFList, "|")(r)
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
          End With
          Do While .Find.Execute
            .Paragraphs.First.Range.Characters.Last.InsertBefore vbCr _ 
              & "Reference: " & Split(xlRList, "|")(r)
            With .Paragraphs.First.Range.Font
              .Bold = True
              .Italic = True
            End With
            With .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Font
              .Bold = False
              .Italic = False
            End With
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          Loop
        End With
      Next
      .Close True
    End With
    .Quit
  End With
Else
  MsgBox "File not found: " & vbCr & StrNm, vbExclamation
End If
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is modifying the Requirement number present in the word document. It only needs to insert the corresponding source of the requirement, not modify the existing requirement number by splitting its req number.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the Req. In bold, italic, but the Source not bold and not italic. The code I posted ensures that's what you end up with. Delete whichever code lines you don't want.

Comment: It is not about font style. When code is executed and when I open word document I am finding this:                                                                                                                     Req
Ref Req: Source _0001

Req
Ref Req: Source _0002
1)The Req is blank without its number.                                                                              2)There is more than one source for Req_0002 (Source_0101, Source_0102)which needs to be displayed using comma as separator. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I run the macro from an Excel workbook with the data you described, against a document with paragraphs containing Req_0001, Req_0002, & Req_0003, I get *exactly* the output you described. The number of Req_0001, etc. is of no consequence - they *all* get processed as per your specifications. The Requirement number is *never* changed. If that is not the result you're getting, it can only be because you have not specified the problem correctly.

Comment: After running the macro is completed, when I open the document I see the Requirement number is not present, only Req is seen and its number is joined with the next line of Reference: Source_0001. This is the issue. I tried by making all (.Bold and .Italic) to False in code and in the word document also, I removed bold and italic to requirement numbers before running the macro . But it is showing the same. Please help to resolve it.@macropod

Comment: Since you haven't properly described your source document's original content and structure anywhere in your problem description, I could only guess at what the problem is. My previous reply describes the content and structure I necessarily assumed your document has.

Comment: The Req_0001 which is there in the excel is already present in the word document and all the requirements which are present in the first column of excel will be present in the word document before running the macro. So macro needs to match the first column of excel Req_0001 to Req_0001 which is present in the word document. So if it matches it needs to insert its corresponding source which is present in the second column of excel to the word document in the next line of Req_0001. If sources are in multiple cells it needs to be separated with (,). This is the thing that macro is intended to do.

Comment: Hi @macropod the code is working as expected. But I am getting Reference: Source wherever Req is present in the document. Ex: If my document contains Request word, it is split into Req Reference: Sourceuest. How to resolve this?

Comment: I suspect that has something to do with a column heading in Excel. Try changing «For r = **1** To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row» to «For r = **2** To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row». Code edited.

Comment: Thanks @macropod it worked. I need one more clarification: If the Req_0001 has a title, consider the Req_0001-First requirement. When we run our existing macro, we get Req_0001 Reference: Source_0100-First Requirement. Because we are inserting the Reference right immediate after the Req_0001 completes(using InsertAfter()). So how to print the Reference in the next line without splitting the Req and its title? like this: Req_0001-First Requirement in the next line Reference: Source_0100.

Comment: Thanks @macropod it's working. One more issue, if Req_0001 is mentioned in the Index or Table of Contents then, the macro is inserting the Reference there also. How to ignore/skip the insertion of Reference from that Index/Table of Contents heading?

Comment: Simply refresh the Table of Contents or Index, as appropriate.

Comment: Tried it. But when Reference is inserted in the document it is creating new Subheading. Ex: Consider 1.1.1.1 Req_0001- First Requirement, when the macro is executed it is creating another subheading like 1.1.1.2 Reference: Source_0100. So to avoid this, I have two titles called Req Objective and Req Method without section numbers. Can we insert our Reference after the Req Objective title? (before Req Method). Req Objective may contain description of the requirement. So after the description Reference: Source_0100 needs to be inserted.

Comment: I'm done wasting time on this. Your problem description has been clearly inadequate from the outset. Moreover, I see no evidence in any of our discussion that you're even trying to address the problems you're encountering because of that. Find someone else's time to waste - preferably your own.